# How woo-commerce store Product Data value in DB?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, parse

I am working on a project in which Products are being added by parsing a XML file.

For Variant product I am able to save all attributes and the product variant related to a product , but I am unable to save "Product Data" drop down value as "Variable Prouduct" using parser ( PHP code ).

Is there any metakey /metavalue for this.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer which I have got

```
// Setting this as a Variable product
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'variable', 'product_type' );
```